# Alternatives to classical softmax for better aggregation

Tags: machine-learning, transformers, attention, graph-neural-network

I am doing machine learning on phylogenetic trees. Species within the trees have several relations, such as living at the same time or not, and I would like to use a global attention mechanism which would allow nodes to interact together, and obtain information about each other.

However, I think the necessary information may be "additive". That is, one species may need to add some features of some specific species it has some relationship with.

I was trying to do that with a classical multi-head attention mechanism, but I think it may not be very well suited: the softmax mechanism kind of enforces selecting a specific node, whereas I would like each node to be able to select several other nodes to interact with.

Do you know if this particular kind of problem has been explored before?